# Full screen width & height in android

Tags: android, android-layout

When i making android design its giving me spacing like we said padding in web how do i make it 100% width.

[image: http://postimg.org/image/fbzzv6dfz/]

here is my layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mobilink.mobilink.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff00cc70"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff0087cc"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ffff1a27"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:background="#ff3444ff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff0019ff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

yeah, please remove

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

from your **RelativeLayout**

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this layout code with your layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    tools:context="com.mobilink.mobilink.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff00cc70"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff0087cc"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ffff1a27"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:background="#ff3444ff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff0019ff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Remove below padding elements from your Relative layout

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```